Attempt by security transparent method Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions
Attempt by security transparent method
Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterControllers(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, System.Reflection.Assembly[])' to access security critical type 'Autofac.Builder.IRegistrationBuilder`3<System.Object,Autofac.Features.Scanning.ScanningActivatorData,Autofac.Builder.DynamicRegistrationStyle>' failed.

Assembly 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' is marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency model.  Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

I am getting this error after upgrading Autofac from 3.5.0 to the latest version i.e. 8.0.0. Getting this security issue related to Autofac.Integration.Mvc. Checked Autofac.Integration.Mvc is a DLL and unable to update that to the latest.
How can I resolve this issue?
I've tried upgrading:

Autofac.MVC5: 6.0.0 - 6.1.0
Autofac.WebApi2: 6.0.0 - 6.1.1

This didn't solve the issue.

Unfortunately, what you have here is a code access security problem, and those are kind of tricky without a lot of information. I recommend you include a minimal reproducible example in your question so folks can see what you see. Include stuff like the .NET version you're on, other dependencies you have, restrictions on the application you're running (web.config info?), etc. Also, include why you can't use the latest versions of things. Errors?
